# how can I decode URL that is not encoded in UTF8 with firefox addons api?

Tags: character-encoding, firefox-addon, decode

I am trying to write a firefox addon and just met this problem.

Firefox seems to encode the search engine URL with the website's charset, suppose we have a word "火", it is means fire in chinese, and we search it with google, the url is

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=g+火&ie=utf-8 ...
```

This url is decoded/unescaped with UTF8, but if I go to  Baidu, a chinese search engine whose charset is gb2312,  we will get the url

```
http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%BB%F0
```

Here BBF0 is the gb2312 code for '火',

How can I get the UTF8 character from some encode(gbk, jp or whatever) with firefox API? I went through the nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter part on develop.mozilla.org, and just can not find the appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

well, I must be confused by how firefox encode its URL, but I just found

```
var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
converter.charset = "gbk";
var car = "%D6%D0%B9%FA";
alert(converter.ConvertToUnicode(unescape("%D6%D0%B0%FA")));
```

will do the trick...